# Visual Studio 2019 not found local IIS Web Site

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I created a web site in .net core 3.1 and I configured local IIS to host it.
When I try to launch debugging from VS 2019 an error alert appears:

[image: Error message]

I suppose to configured IIS correctly...

[image: Site bindings]

This is the application pool:

[image]

what am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is a VS configuration for debug:

[image: vs configuration]

**SOLVED**

In addition to set static ip in the router configuration, I set static ip in the windows configuration.

Now it's work!

Comment: It says “host name” on the error, maybe it wants you to have a site with that host name, not just IP?

Comment: would you please show us the configuration being applied in Project Properties/Web section in VS?

Comment: I want use my machine ip to host web site, for debug.

Comment: It worked for me with a different solution. Check the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75096654/vs-2022-net-core-3-1-web-app-cant-debug-under-iis-profile/76357544#76357544

Answer (score 1):

You can change the IP address from 192.168.1.50 to something else which is available in IIS binding section and check if it works

[image]

[image]