# VS 2022 + .NET Core 3.1 Web app can't debug under IIS profile

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I receive the following error when trying to debug the .net core web app under the IIS profile.

[image]

launchSettings.json is as follows and the PC IP is correct. (192.168.31.107)

[image]

"cqrs" site is also created in IIS and with a separate app pool (CLR version: No managed code)
The URL (http://192.168.31.107/cqrs/swagger/index.html) also works when typed into the browser. The only issue is when hit F5 from VS 2022 I get the popup error and can't debug.

Hope this info is enough for you to let me know how to fix this. Please don't hesitate to ask for more info, I'll be happy to provide it.

If I change the `application URL` to "http://**localhost**/cqrs" then the VS2022 lets me hit F5 and debug. But I want the web app to run with the IP, not with `localhost`.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385404/visual-studio-2019-not-found-local-iis-web-site) and tried everything. Nothing works.

Thanks again.

Comment: You have to edit the question to reveal the site bindings you set for the IIS site, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked for me by modifying the `host` file in Windows.

```
c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

When the app runs with Docker, it updates the host file with the PC IP and its own DNS name. By simply commenting out it stated working.

[image]